# Can't get Facebook page info using app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, gcloud

The problem is that I can't get info about this page https://www.facebook.com/WonderfulPosts/ using my application. 
I have tried to do that in graph API sandbox and from my web page but still nothing.
I did some research and find out that if page blocked for US region I can't get it. We are using gcloud server with us-central1 zone I think this is a part of a problem.
 According to page owner words, he blocked this page in some regions but NOT for US.

But for example, this service can get page info without problems with any regional settings http://findmyfbid.com/

Is it Facebook app settings or some server settings problem? I can't understand

Comment: _“We are using gcloud server with us-central1 zone I think this is a part of a problem”_ – that has absolutely nothing to do with it. Your Facebook page is not hosted on your server, but on Facebook’s. And the “block” is about the settings for the FB page, who can access it. Your own server does not come into play at all.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I already get it. I was confused and start digging in wrong way because I was unable to get data even with my FB user access_tocen in Graph API Explorer, the problem was solved after the password was updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Page is restricted by age or location, you need to use a User Token (of a User who is able to see the Page), or a Page Token (if you own the Page).

Comment: Thanks, I just figure it out myself. After updating my account password I can get this page info in graph api sandbox and if I use this token in my web application it works. But now I wonder what was wrong with my account before today)